# Parameterizing XPath for modify() in SQL Server XML Processing

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

Just like the title suggests, I'm trying to parameterize the XPath for a modify() method for an XML data column in SQL Server, but running into some problems.

So far I have:

```
DECLARE @newVal varchar(50)
DECLARE @xmlQuery varchar(50)
SELECT @newVal = 'features'
SELECT @xmlQuery = 'settings/resources/type/text()'

UPDATE  [dbo].[Users]
SET     [SettingsXml].modify('
    replace value of (sql:variable("@xmlQuery"))[1]
    with sql:variable("@newVal")')
WHERE   UserId = 1
```

with the following XML Structure:

```
<settings>
    ...
    <resources>
        <type> ... </type>
        ...
    </resources>
    ...
</settings>
```

which is then generating this error:

`XQuery [dbo.Users.NewSettingsXml.modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'xs:string ?'`

Now I realize that the modify method must not be capable of accepting a string as a path, but is there a way to accomplish this short of using dynamic SQL?

Oh, by the way, I'm using SQL Server 2008 Standard 64-bit, but any queries I write need to be compatible back to 2005 Standard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone was interested, I came up with a pretty decent solution myself using a dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @newVal nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @xmlQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @id int

SET @newVal = 'foo'
SET @xmlQuery = '/root/node/leaf/text()'
SET @id = 1

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

SET @query = '
    UPDATE  [Table]
    SET     [XmlColumn].modify(''
        replace value of (' + @xmlQuery + '))[1]
        with sql:variable("@newVal")'')
    WHERE Id = @id'

EXEC sp_executesql @query,
                   N'@newVal nvarchar(max) @id int',
                   @newVal, @id
```

Using this, the only unsafe part of the dynamic query is the xPath, which, in my case, is controlled entirely by my code and so shouldn't be exploitable.

Answer (score 2):

The best I could figure out was this:

```
declare @Q1 varchar(50)
declare @Q2 varchar(50)
declare @Q3 varchar(50)
set @Q1 = 'settings'
set @Q2 = 'resources'
set @Q3 = 'type'

UPDATE  [dbo].[Users]
SET     [SettingsXml].modify('
    replace value of (for $n1 in /*,
                          $n2 in $n1/*,
                          $n3 in $n2/*
                      where $n1[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Q1")] and
                            $n2[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Q2")] and
                            $n3[local-name(.) = sql:variable("@Q3")]
                      return $n3/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@newVal")')
WHERE   UserId = 1
```

Node names are parameters but the level/number of nodes is sadly not.

Comment: That would be a good solution, but unfortunately, I have an arbitrary number of levels in this case so it seems it would make it sloppy. I think, unless I find another good answer, I'm gonna go with a dynamic query even though I have reservations about it due to safety concerns. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Seeing your use of the `local-name(.)` function helped me tremendously.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution we found for parameterizing both the property name to be replaced and the new value. It needs a specific xpath, and the parameter name can be an sql variable or table column.

```
SET Bundle.modify
(
  'replace value of(//config-entry-metadata/parameter-name[text() = sql:column("BTC.Name")]/../..//value/text())[1] with sql:column("BTC.Value") '
)
```

This is the hard coded x path: `//config-entry-metadata/parameter-name ... /../..//value/text()`
The name of the parameter is dynamic: `[text() = sql:column("BTC.Name")]`
The new value is also dynamic: `with sql:column("BTC.Value")`