# TSQL XML_DML: Convert a Varchar value to a String literal value

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I tried to create a stored procedure which can pass a xml_dml command into the procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SO_UpdateXMLFile]
    @xmldml varchar(max),
    @soid varchar(20)
AS
    UPDATE SO_Info 
    SET Eqm_Evaluation_Results.modify( @xmldml)
    WHERE SO_Id = @soid 
GO
```

But I failed to create it with this error

> "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string
>   literal."

Have any one got any ideas how to convert a Varchar to a string literal ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterizing XPath for modify() in SQL Server XML Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346727/parameterizing-xpath-for-modify-in-sql-server-xml-processing)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the link you gave me didn't solve the problem. I want to pass the whole 'xml dml' command to my procedure as a parameter. But it said that it must be a string literal not a normal string. That's why I need to know how to convert a normal string to a string literal in TSQL. Do you have any idea ?