# Use variable in xml path in xml.modify

Tags: sql-server, xml

Edit:  SQL Server 2016.  I'm running several xml.modify statements that all use pretty much the same path.  I originally put an example that didn't match my error.
I'm trying to substitute the 'a/b/' in the path with the value in the variable @a.
Here's what I'm using:

```
declare @ab varchar(5) = 'a/b/'
declare @xml xml = '<root><a><b><c><d></d></c></b></a></root>'
-- works
--set @xml.modify('insert attribute MyAtt {"No"} into (/root/a/b/c/d)[1]')
-- error
set @xml.modify('insert attribute MyAtt {"Yes"} into (/root/{sql:variable("@ab")}c/d)[1]')
select @xml
```

but I get a different error

```
Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
XQuery [modify()]: Syntax error near '{', expected a step expression.
```

There is no mismatch in {(, etc.  I tried removing the braces and/or the double quotes around the variable name.  No luck. Is this even possible?  And if so, what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346727/parameterizing-xpath-for-modify-in-sql-server-xml-processing

Comment: According to the error message you're missing a `)` character: `insert attribute MyAtt {"Yes"} into (/root/a/b/c/d//1` needs a terminating `)` at the end.